# Problems with overflow and :before absolute

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, absolute

I have a problem when I add `overflow-x:hidden` to my container the image I have that is absolute that is displayed outside of the container gets inside the container. I dont want that but same time I want the `overflow-x:hidden`.

Html looks like this

```
<ul id="groups-menu" class="dropdown-menu notif" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
etc..
</ul>
```

This is the css:

```
#groups-menu.dropdown-menu.notif {
max-height: 900px;
overflow-x: hidden; <-- When I add this the the :before image gets inside the container
left: -143px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-right-width: 2px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
background-clip: padding-box;
margin: 2px 0 0;
}
```

This is the image I want on top outside of the container

```
.dropdown-menu.notif:before {
background-image: url("notif.png");
content: "";
display: inline-block;
height: 11px;
left: 166px;
position: absolute;
top: -11px;
width: 22px;
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: this is a common mistake - the before actually adds it to the element but before any content within that element, just add a wrapper element to the ul and style a before on the wrapper

Comment: @Pete could you show me what you mean

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z6WBw/ - you can see the image is outside the ul